# Display row with mySQLI

Tags: php, mysqli, printf

I'm trying to display all the data for the row where its what the user enters. I have this code but it does not display any of the variables :(

```
$db = new mysqli("127.0.0.1", "root", "", "classic");

if (mysqli_connect_errno())
    {
    echo "Noes, we could not complete your request! Quote error code S69 when contacting tech support!";
    exit();
    }
// variables
$modelToDlete = strip_tags($_POST['deleteMe']);

if (isset($_POST['submit']))
    {

$deleteCar = $db->prepare("SELECT `model`, `price`, `miles`, `engineSize`, `color`, `description`, `regNo` FROM `cardetails` WHERE `carID` =?") or die($db->error);
$deleteCar->bind_param('s', $modelToDlete);
$deleteCar->execute();
$result = $deleteCar->bind_result($model, $price, $miles, $engineSize, $color, $desc, $regno);

printf("Detais of the car you want to delete: ", $model, $price, $miles, $engineSize, $color, $desc, $regno);
}//if
```

?>

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the placeholders in your `printf()` statement (assuming string values):

```
printf("Detais of the car you want to delete: %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s", $model, $price, $miles, $engineSize, $color, $desc, $regno);
```